# How can I create a Big array in an optimized way

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization

I'm creating a web simulator for the RISC-V processor assembly. Right at the end of code development I came across a problem that I didn't notice at the beginning of development.

The RISC-V RV32I processor has a memory size of 32 bits, that is, it is 4,294,967,296 in decimal. However as each element is 4 bytes, I divide 4,294,967,296 / 4 and there are 1,073,741,824 elements left.

I need to define a way to store 1,073,741,824 elements in an array, this is impossible as there is a size limit. I thought about dividing by blocks, but I still couldn't do it in an optimized way.

Have you ever worked with data of a similar size? Is there a way to do this optimally? I want to do this without using a database or anything like that. I'm just using angular, since I can upload it to github pages for free.

Currently, I simulated the two processor memories with a very small size, however I need to create this memory that takes the entire size of the processor, the idea is to have a file/variable in which I pass the address and return the element of that address.

```
    const map = new Map<number, any>();
    for (let i = 0; i < 4294967296; i++) {
      map.set(i * 4, 0);
    }
    return map;
```

I tried to make a simple code, but this is impossible, and it is not optimized at all.
If anyone has any ideas, I would be very grateful.

Comment: There is a reason why 32 bit processors like the Pentium etc. were limited to smaller sizes. There are tricks to use 2/3 GiB per process but that won't safe you if you want to use a full 4 GiB. Of course, you cannot directly address more than that, but you can still create files of over 4 GiB as disk addressing isn't limited to that. Maybe you can do some memory mapping of a file or similar, but that would be tricky as well. Anyway, this doesn't feel like a job for a RISC-V, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm creating a RISC-V assembly web simulator, so I need a variable/file that simulates the memory size (1,073,741,824 elements), for data insertion and visualization

Comment: If you write your own MMU then you can use multiple arrays, correct? And why do you need to support the whole memory size? Even if something is mapped to the top of the memory you wouldn't need to simulate everything in between.

Comment: I want to store 1,073,741,824 elements in some variable or array or file, how would I write an MMU in js? I want to be able to view my memories, so I need it all.

Comment: I think this answer would become a bit long winded if I'm going into all steps of how to simulate an MMU in JS, even ChatGPT gives about 2 pages of info when I ask for the general principles without including JS. Don't think that simulating a modern CPU is something easy, even if it has "reduced instruction set" literally in the name.

Comment: I just want to simulate the memory, the rest is ready, here is my processor: https://eduardomichell.github.io/rv-sim/
In this case there are two memories after you do the assemble, currently there are two arrays of 10 pages, I want to simulate the entire memory there, so I wanted to know how to store 1 billion data in an array

Comment: I don't get it. You can store enough *page references* in an array of type object, correct? Why do you want to address these bytes individually while you can split the address into page reference (msb) and location in the page (lsb)? Heck you can even do virtual memory if you want to, for that you'd need a *page table*.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](https://chat.openai.com/share/39fdeadf-8ef3-43ef-a247-c5b1b9d91901). You could of course search a bit more about common implementations of the page table in RISC-V (link to ChatGPT).

Comment: I believe I'm going to create a virtual memory, it's the best idea

Answer (score 2):

```
    const map = new Map<number, any>();
    for (let i = 0; i < 4294967296; i++) {
      map.set(i * 4, 0);
    }
    return map;
```

By pre-filling the map like this, you're losing out on the key advantage of it: flexibility. You can avoid putting any zero elements in the map by defining a missing key to mean that the memory at that address is zero. If someone writes a program that actually uses all 4GB of theoretically available memory, it will require all that memory, but most people who use a simulator like this won't use all available memory.

One of the disadvantages of a data structure like this is that the flexibility of this approach also makes it relatively inefficient. I'm not experienced in Javascript, but it seems like this would require 24 bytes for each map key plus 8 bytes for the number stored in the map. Given that you're storing 4 bytes of data, that implies that the map approach would make this require 8x as much storage space as is necessary.

One way to avoid that would be to make an observation about how computers use memory: computers tend to not use random addresses to write data. Rather, they tend to write to addresses that are next to each other.

You can take advantage of this observation by changing how you store values. Rather than store each 4 bytes value in the map, you can store a chunk of N bytes. In each key for the map, rather than storing the address of the data, you store the address divided by N, then floored. To find the index within each chunk, you can take the address modulo N.

Psuedocode:

```
map is a map of page numbers to arrays
N = 65536
function get(address) {
    page = floor(address / N)
    within_page_index = address % N
    if map has page {
        return map.get(page)[address / 4]
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
function set(address, value) {
    page = floor(address / N)
    within_page_index = address % N
    if map has page {
        new_page = new array[N]
        new_page[within_page_index / 4] = value
        map.set(page, new_page)
    } else {
        old_page = map.get(page)
        new_page[within_page_index / 4] = value
    }
}
```

Note on the choice of the value of N: I would suggest a value of N somewhere in the range of 1024-65536, and I would suggest that you make it a power of 2. If you make it a power of 2, then `floor(address / N)` can be done with just a shift, and `address % N` can be done with a bitwise AND of `address & (N - 1)`, which is cheaper than modulo.

Comment: A map probably still has a maximum count of elements that it contains. And usually there is some predefined page size which you could use.

Comment: I understand the code, but I need to have this space somewhere, because I need to see every piece of memory, even if the value is 0, I put map as an example, but it could be a simple array too, with the element index being the address. Maybe I separate this into several smaller arrays, and pre-create it and leave it in some file, I'll try with your code to see what I can do, but in your case it creates a map when I only have one element, but I want to have it created the size I want with zero elements

Comment: @Eduardo "I need to see every piece of memory, even if the value is 0" I'm not sure I understand - how would you visualize a billion memory locations? It seems like you need to restrict the number of elements of memory which are shown on-screen, and anything which is both off-screen and zero doesn't need to be stored.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I looked into that - it seems like a map has a limit of 2^24 elements, which would preclude values of N < 256. I agree that you could match the page size in this code to the operating system's page size, but it's not clear to me that you'd gain any particular benefit from doing so, which is why I didn't mention it.

Comment: @NickODell So, I can't do that because the user can view the entire memory, even if there is no data, I thought about creating a code that adds memory to each page he is on, but there will come a time when the program will stop working because there was no space to add "memory" to the array

Comment: @Eduardo In the solution I posted, it adds memory every time that the virtual CPU writes to memory. If the user views an area of memory which hasn't been written to, the code above returns zero in that case, so from the user's perspective it is indistinguishable.

Comment: @NickODell I ended up using this solution that you showed, I don't need to allocate 4gb if I don't use 4gb, so I just show everything as 0 and if there is an element in that position I show it to the user, thanks for the help!